# How to prove convergence of $\int_0^1f\left(\sqrt x \right)dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Could you please give me some hint how to prove convergence of
$\int_0^1f\left(\sqrt x \right)dx$

when f(x) is continuous for $0<x\le1$ and $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^3f^2(x)=1$ ?

I tried the usual way: $\int_0^1f\left(\sqrt x \right)dx=\left[y=\sqrt x \right]=2\int_0^1\frac{f(y)}y dy$.

From $\lim_{x\to0^+}x^3f^2(x)=1$ we can conclude that for all $0<x<\lambda<1$
$\frac 1{2x^3}\le f^2(x)\le \frac 3{2x^3}$, therefore $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx$ diverges.But how divergence of $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx$ is connected to convergence of $\int_0^1f\left(\sqrt x \right)dx$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: So...  $f(x) \sim x^{-3/2}$ and then $f(\sqrt{x}) \sim x^{-3/4}$...

Comment: I think this asyptotic is enough to prove the convergence.